# Design interface for SSIS precedence constraints

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

VS 15.9.18
MS SQL Server Data Tools for VS2017

Just a couple of speedbumps which have always annoyed when when working with SSIS packages in VS.

1. You create an execution precedence constraint by "grabbing" the little green stub from one executable and dragging it to another.  Is there any keyboard shortcut to create a precedence constraint that *isn't* "Success"?  It's a total pain to create dozens of constraints and then have to "clicky click clicky - **** I can't hit it I'm a DWH dev not a Call of Duty sharpshooter!" on each one then change it to e.g. "Completion".
2. Is there actually any way to hook up the resulting line to a specific face of either executable?  The defaults VS chooses are often bizarre: you have to re-arrange things to placate the mysterious VS layout gods and get something that's visually readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No keyboard shortcuts exist that I am aware of. If it could be a keyboard click, you would find it via Tools, Options, Environment -> Keyboard. I'm not finding any SSIS specific shortcuts in there, much less one for precedent constraints.

The layout is an after thought because it only matters when your designing the package. When packages run on the server, the layout is not used. Instead, the control flow objects "know" how they interact with each other.

I find using [Biml](http://www.bimlscript.com/) to design my packages reduces my mouse clicks and let me just write the code. No CoD mouse skills required.

Comment: True that the layout is irrelevant to actual operation.  I still like a neat package layout, makes it far easier to figure out what's going on.